# Console errors after installing Magento-CE-2.0.2

Tags: admin, console

> I freshly installed Magento 2.02 Community Edition but now when i
>   login to admin panel then nothing is clickable and found 28 console
>   error related to css and js  How can i solve this problem

[image: Screen Shot of admin panell]

Comment: dont use `/localhost/` create virtual domain name and add it to your `/etc/hosts`  file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

- step 1. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- step 2. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- step 3. make sure apache "rewrite_module" is enable and then restart
  the server
- step 4. delete cache folder under `var/cache`

Comment: How can i run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ? i mean from where should i give command

Comment: run from magento root folder, and you must run these commands as user who owns your files... if you run as root you need to switch user `su user -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"`